# What should be the general formula for the following permutation problem?

Tags: probability

If $q$ number of elements are scheduled only to stay together, without having any specific order, what would be the permutation of $r$ elements taken from $n$ elements?

For example, suppose we have 5 alphabets $A, B, C, E, F$. If A and E always stay together, how many permutations are possible if we use 3 characters at a time?

In this case, 12 results are possible: $AEB$, $AEC$, $AEF$, $BAE$, $BEA$, $CAE$, $CEA$, $EAB$, $EAC$, $EAF$, $FAE$, $FEA$?

What would be the general formula to calculate this kind of problem?

Comment: Are all n elements distinct?

Comment: Are the p elements fixed or to be chosen?

Comment: Are not $\rm BCF, BFC, CBF, CFB, FBC, FCB$ also possible selection? Where $A$ and $E$ stay together yet unselected.

Comment: What do you mean by " q elements are fixed with A and E"? Do i get to choose them ? Like ABC instead of AE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose out of n elements, q elements stay together, then we can consider a total of n - q elements and one additional group. Also, as those q elements can further have different permutations, we have to take additional factor of q! multiplied with the terms which include that group in them and as per your statement, the group seems to be always included.

So, we could rather make it easy by saying that instead of finding permutations of r elements, we will have permutations of r - q elements from n - q elements (note that the 1 group is left as of now). Let the result here be a (i.e. number of ways to choose r - q from n - q elements). Now we can place that group in r - q + 1 positions which can further have q! permutations.

So overall we have, $q! \times (r - q + 1) \times ^{n-q}P_{r-q}$.

I am assuming you can't group more elements than the ones to be choosen as you seem to always include that group.

Comment: @MorganRodgers i don't think so. for example, we have joint part "abc" and other part "de", this will make "abcde" and "abced" same. whereas they are considered different in the question. so we have to find permutations, not combinations.

Comment: @MorganRodgers sorry but it's only (r-q+1) here, not factorial. can you please check out my logic in the answer again and tell me if i am wrong? q! takes care of internal orderings in the group, (r-q+1) are the ways (or positions) in which we can place the group there. rest is for the permutations of other chatacters.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we must consider $r>q$. So we will consider the $q$ elements to be a single element. Thus no. of elements that I have to arrange is $(r-q+1)$.

These $(r-q+1)$ things are all distinct things and can be arranged in $(r-q+1)!$ ways. Then the $q$ things can arrange themselves in $q!$ ways. So total no. of arrangements will be $(r-q+1)! \times q!$.

Now you have to multiply the factor containing no. of ways in which $r-q$ things can be chosen from $n-q$ things.

Comment: $q! (r-q+1)! ^{n}P_{r}$ = 240. The answer should be 12.

Comment: @anonymous r things can be chosen from n things in $^nC_r$ ways, not in $^nP_r$ ways. Correct that please and multiply and tell me if the result matches now..Moreover it wont be r,n any longer for you have mentioned that n are all distinct and that q are fixed. So you are to multiply by $^{n-q}C_{r-q}$

Comment: @anonymous Are you kidding?? As by your example, n=5,q=2 and r=3 and the formula yields answer 12. Please recheck your calculations

Comment: ok. yes. i got it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need $q \le r \le n$. Looking at you example it seems that you have to choose r elements among witch there are the q elements that have to stay toghether (maybe you didn't consider the possibility that there could be choices of r elements whithout any of the q elements). Under this hypotesis you have to choose the other $r-q$ elements among n-q: then you have $\binom {n-q}{r-q}$ choices. You than have to give them an order: you have $r!$ ways to do so. Hence you have 
$$r!\binom{n-q}{r-q}
$$ choices for you permutations. In your example $3!\binom{5-2}{3-2}=3\times 3!=18$ you missed some terms, for example ACE.

Comment: You're wrong.By together, he means A will be beside E i.e. AE or EA

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question! Then you just need to treat the q terms as one and find the permutations of r+1 elements as I did. Then motice that you can put the q elements in q! ways once chosen where to put the q elements "together"

Comment: @NicolòRuggeri, my answer is 12. See the example in the question. Your answer is producing 18.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, my answer is 12. See the example in the question. Your answer is producing 6.

Answer (score 0):

There are $n$ distinct elements from which we select and arrange $r$ (without repletion), where $q$ of these elements must remain together in a block.   It's not specified that they must be *used*, so we'll consider both cases.

Case (1): If $q\leq r$ we count ways to select those elements and $r-q$ from the $n-q$ remaining, arrange those $q$ elements within their block, and arrange the block *and* the $r-q$ elements.

Case (2): If $r\leq n-q$, we count ways to select $r$ elements from $n-q$.

Putting it together:$$\frac{(n-q)!\,q!\,(r-q+1)!}{(r-q)!\,(n-r)!}\,\mathbf 1_{q\leq r}+\frac{(n-q)!}{(n-q-r)!}\,\mathbf 1_{r\leq n-q}$$

**Note:** If those $q$ elements must be used, then disregard the last term.